# Feature graphic shows up in Android Market, but not for devices

Tags: android, google-play

The feature graphic for [my app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.badwaterstudios.CinchDroidFree) is showing up for the Android Market listing when viewed from a PC, but not on devices.  This was pointed out to me in the [Friday Review](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKo1gKtgxFk) (at about 18:45 in), where they also mention that adding a feature graphic would fix the issue of missing a banner.

The feature graphic was uploaded when I first submitted the application, and has been there ever since.  I also have a promotional graphic uploaded for the submission.

The sizes match the requirements mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1078870) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-market-featured-image.html), and I saved them in the same format as the screenshots for the listing, which do show up on the Market listing from a device.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated--thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature graphics aren't intended to show up when you are browsing Android market with your phone.

Comment: This is what I thought, but per what they say during the review: "There's no banner...If you have no banner, our marketing department can't feature you.  It's impossible.  You need to go into your market account and upload a feature graphic."

Still, I've looked at other featured apps and I don't notice anything different between their listing and mine.  I sent a message to support, which apparently has terrible turnaround time, but if that's what they answer as well I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what they were pointing out?

Comment: What review are you talking about? Note: As from my own experience, you probably wont be receiving response from Android market team in the nearest future.

Comment: The dev advocates looked at my app on the Friday Review, which is linked to in my post.  They mentioned it there.